# 'it refers not to ...' vs. 'it doesn't refer to ...'

Tags: grammar

> For me it refers ***not*** to the store and ***not*** to the one clerk you spoke to but collectively to the not-further-specified people who work there.

Is the structure of that sentence, in reference to how 'not' is used, an excellent way to circumvent the use of the modal 'do'?

I ask because, as a non-native speaker and not a linguist, I would have written the above sentence as follows:

> ​1. For me it ***doesn't*** refer to the store and ***doesn't*** refer to the one clerk you spoke to but collectively to the not-further-specified people who work there.

or perhaps:

> ​2. For me it ***doesn't*** refer to the store and to the one clerk you spoke to but collectively to the not-further-specified people who work there.

If the original version is grammatical, can I generalize that use of 'not' to other cases, for example "I'm going not to answer, but to waiting an answer"?

Comment: The auxiliary *do* here doesn't have modal meaning.  In fact, it has no meaning at all; it is inserted in your examples only to support *-n't*.

Comment: I would change example 2 from *and* to *or*: "For me it doesn't refer to the store ***or*** to the one clerk you spoke to but ..."

Comment: I'm not sure this answers your question, but you should realize that we don't write "It refers not to X," as a complete sentence. We only use this construction when we follow it up with an alternative: "It refers not to X but to Y." This construction is grammatical but a bit formal or dry or even clumsy. Your examples with "doesn't" are closer to what would be used in casual speech.

Comment: @snail, but I was taught to use the do-support in sentences in which a negation is involved, i.e. 'I don't like swimming', not, to say the same thing, 'I like not swimming'. Why would the case in the question be different?

Comment: @user2793 That's exactly what snailboat means: *do* in this instance doesn't add any nuance of modal meaning, it's a "dummy" auxiliary which is only there to support the negation. In fact, *do* is never a 'modal' in the technical sense: unlike the modals it has a full set of inflections, including distinct 3sg and participial forms, and it can be deployed as an infinitive.

Comment: I once heard that Old English has no auxiliary, e.g. instead of saying *"You do not know ..."*, they say *Thou knowest not what a day may bring forth.* (Also note that this *thou* is a singular *you*.) Since this can still be found in bible, I think it's quite natural to say *"It refers not to ..."* I sometimes heard this in lectures or presentations, and found that the stress on "not" seems to give a stronger impact than "doesn't".

Comment: @DamkerngT. It's just as The Photon said.  "It refers not to X" is archaic, so it wouldn't be natural in modern English.  "It refers not to X but to Y" is natural, though, because *not* doesn't directly negate the verb; it appears as part of a **correlative coordination**: "It refers [ not [ to X ] but [ to Y ] ]"

Answer (score 1):

> For me it refers not to the store and not to the one clerk you spoke to but collectively to the not-further-specified people who work there.

I would write it this way:

1a) For me, it refers not/neither to the store or to the one clerk you spoke to but collectively to the not-further-specified people who work there.

or

1b) For me, it doesn't refer to the store or to the one clerk you spoke to but refers/does collectively to the not-further-specified people who work there.

However, when you write the sentence following independently, it may be a little awkward. It is possible under some circumstances, though.

> It refers not to the store.

Let's get back to the sentence 1a. You can rephrase it to:

> For me it refers collectively to the not-further-specified people who work there, not to the store or to the one clerk you spoke to.

You use "not" to make a comparison of the phrases "to the store/the clerk" and "to the not-further-specified people". This is the reason why the sentence 1a sounds OK.